# Unsubscribe Link w/ Business Email not Merchant ID

Tags: paypal

I'm creating a "dynamic" unsubscribe link for PayPal subscriptions. All I have to work with is the users PayPal email address. I can create a link like this:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=email%40domain.tld
or
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=email@domain.tld

both of which produce this error in PayPal:

> The unsubscribe button you clicked is invalid. You can find the status
>   of all subscriptions in 'My preapproved payments'.

When I use my own Merchant ID it works as expected. I cannot find any documentation on PayPal's site about what other argument I can use to get this to work. Everything I read says that email@domain.tld is an acceptable argument for the alias key.

Answer (score 0):

What documentation tells you to use email? Can you share a link please?
You used to be able to append the email in the past, but not any longer.

You'll need to request the 'secure merchant account ID' / 'merchant ID' / 'payer ID' from the merchants, or call the `GetPalDetails` API call on their behalf / for them.

Unfortunately there is no way around this.

Comment: Bit of necromancy here, but the problem with this is that you can't test the unsuscribe stuff from a sandbox environment.